# Problem in libtiff.dll when starting QGIS

Tags: qgis

When I try to start QGIS 1.8.0 I get the error message "*Can't find procedure start address TIFFMergerFieldInfo in libtiff.dll*" and the program won't start. I have downloaded and reinstalled QGIS several times, but it does not help. What to do? Any suggestions? I have noticed that this problem is not unique to me, but I have not found a remedy.

Comment: It's not a QGIS problem. That's why reinstalling doesn't change anything. It's a problem in your system caused by other applications which installed their incompatible DLLs in windows system folders.

Answer (score 1):

The work-around to this issue is to rename **libtiff.dll** in your **windows\system32** folder, then restart QGIS. You can either:

- rename the file to something like libtiff.dll.bak, OR
- rename the file (as above) then copy libtiff.dll from your QGIS install folder to windows\system32

The following links identified this work-around.

- http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/3861 (4th entry in *Change History*)
- http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Problems-to-install-QGIS-1-8-on-Windows-XP-td4987425.html
- http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/QGIS-starting-problem-td4753839.html